# Can I pass a computed property and an object inside a v-bind:class in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to understand if I can do something like this, because I am trying but only getting erros... Forgive my bad english.

HTML file would be something like

`<p :class="{mycss: isActive}, myComputedProperty" > My text </p>`

and the component file would have something like

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myComputedProperty () {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what errors you are seeing?

Comment: Module build failed (from .........):SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: The error happens in another place and irrelevant to the question. The syntax is valid, it just won't give the intended result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` value is an expression. If it doesn't make sense in raw JavaScript, it doesn't make sense there. Here comma operator is used, so the expression evaluates to `myComputedProperty`, and `{mycss: isActive}` part is discarded.

The format for combined `class` value is [documented](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax):

```
:class="[{mycss: isActive}, myComputedProperty]"
```

Since computed values are involved, defining the whole `class` object as a computed will result in cleaner template code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your HTML - the comma is probably the cause. There are lots of ways to format strings, but this is one option:

```
<p :class="isActive ? 'mycss ' + myComputedProperty : myComputedProperty" > My text </p>
```

Comment: Still not it, the error is the same as before
```SyntaxError: Unexpected token```
Also believe the error is in HTML, but don't know if I can use an ```object``` and a ```computed property``` together

Comment: Did you try the line of code I posted in my answer? The unexpected token originally was your comma. That line of code should be valid.

Comment: Actually, the comma was expected. It should be parsed as JS comma operator. `({mycss: isActive}, myComputedProperty) === myComputedProperty`